# Cannot read property 'SessionRequest' of undefined at initializeCastApi

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chromecast

My code is giving me the error

```
Cannot read property 'SessionRequest' of undefined
    at initializeCastApi
```

I don't know what happened it used to work.
Essentially when I click the check boxes a request gets made and customer application will be displayed on the chrome casts. I can't even get the session to start.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="//www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script>
    <script src="//www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"

<script type="text/javascript">
    var applicationID = 'F69D8642';
    var namespace = 'urn:x-cast:com.website';
    var session = null;

    /*

     /** Disable right click on Main screen
     document.onmousedown=disableclick;
     function disableclick(event)
     {
     if(event.button==2)
     {
     return false;
     }
     }


     <body oncontextmenu="return false">
     */

     /**
     **************************************************************************************
     ********                    Call initialization for Cast                      ********
     **************************************************************************************
     */
    if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
        setTimeout(initializeCastApi, 1000);
    }

    /**
     **************************************************************************************
     ********                            initialization                            ********
     **************************************************************************************
     */
    function initializeCastApi() {
        console.log("initializeCastApi : " + applicationID);
        var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
        var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
                sessionListener, receiverListener);

        chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onError);
    };
```

Comment: An error message like this means that the parent object is not present, specifically `chrome.cast` and indeed, there's [no such API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) for extensions.

Comment: If that is the case how was this working before? It stopped working about 2 weeks ago without a single change being made. How would I change that or implement that?

Comment: I guess this is a chrome app, not an extension, and it stopped working because something's changed. If not your app, then it's Chrome. Try in an older portable version.

Comment: what I had suspected was the new upgrade to the CAF receiver. Could that have anything to do with it? However the only thing with that was that the chrome.cast.sessionrequest is still available thorough the sender API... so again not really sure if that's what it is

Comment: you know what i download an older version and it works. I have encountered a different problem, but at least I can access it now. Thanks, eventually I will have to move everything to CAF though, but for the meantime it can cast.